# How do I test a method gets called in a Sinatra controller?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I'm trying to test that a method gets called in my Sinatra controller using Rspec. I'm making a clone of Twitter for a mini-project, and want to make sure that every time a new user signs up, an email gets sent.

This works using Mailgun, a ruby gem, and emails have been sent out once a new user signs up.

The problem is in the testing. I've written a method in the controller called send_mail that only gets called when the user signs up. Ignore the contents of this method, they're not that important for the purposes of this question. Just know that it works.

```
def send_email
  RestClient::Request.execute(
  url: "https://api:key-7af11fe0adc2a642e55d33744117e7d2"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox1aad2b9369f348018e3b435a1026927c.mailgun.org/messages",
  :method => :post,
  :payload => {
  :from => 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox1aad2b9369f348018e3b435a1026927c.mailgun.org>',
  :sender => 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox1aad2b9369f348018e3b435a1026927c.mailgun.org>',
  :to => params[:email],
  :subject => "Welcome to Chitter",
  :text => "Welcome to Adrian's awesome Chitter site. " + params[:username] + ".Get Chittering!",
  :multipart => true
  },
  :headers => {
    :"h:X-My-Header" => "www/mailgun-email-send"
  },
  :verify_ssl => false
  )
end
```

This method (send_email) gets called in the post request on the 8th line below.

```
  post '/users' do
@user = User.create(email: params[:email],
            username: params[:username],
            password: params[:password],
            password_confirmation: params[:password_confirmation])

if @user.save
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  send_email
  redirect '/peeps'
else
  flash.now[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
  erb :'users/new'
end
end
```

I've written a bunch of tests, one to test that the app even responds to the method, and second to test that the send_email method is being called when a new user signs up.

```
describe Chitter do
include Rack::Test::Methods

def app
 Chitter.new!
end

it 'has send_email method' do
 expect(app).to respond_to :send_email
end

it 'sends a message to the user when user signs up' do
 allow_any_instance_of(RestClient::Request).to receive(:execute).with(any_args)
 post '/users', params={email: "example@email.com", 
                      username: "Adrian17", 
                      password: "adrian1", 
                      password_confirmation: 'adrian1'}
 expect(app).to have_received(:send_email)
end
```

Our first test passes (the app should respond to send_email) but the second one doesn't. The error message we get is saying the method has not been stubbed.

```
Failure/Error: expect(app).to have_received(:send_email)
   #<Chitter:0x007f959e8e3088> expected to have received send_email, but that object is not a spy or method has not been stubbed.
```

Many hours have been spent on this, with varying pairs of eyes giving it a go, but nothing we do has managed to make this test pass. Any guidance on where we might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
it 'sends a message to the user when user signs up' do
  allow_any_instance_of(RestClient::Request).to receive(:execute).with(any_args)
  expect(app).to receive(:send_email)
  post '/users', params={email: "example@email.com", 
                      username: "Adrian17", 
                      password: "adrian1", 
                      password_confirmation: 'adrian1'}
end
```

That should get you flying!